# Huggingface QA model results decoding

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm trying work with a transformer model (for the question answering task). I am submitting a short string as an input example.

It's my simplest code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch

#Model downloaded from https://huggingface.co/KseniyaZ/sbert_large_nlu_ru
    
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("KseniyaZ/sbert_large_nlu_ru")
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("KseniyaZ/sbert_large_nlu_ru")
        
s = 'Hi. How are you?' #simple string with question
tok = tokenizer(s, return_tensors='pt')
res = model(**tok)
print(res)
```

The output is the following:

```
QuestionAnsweringModelOutput(loss=None, start_logits=tensor([[ 2.2755,  0.3885, -1.9400]], grad_fn=<CloneBackward0>), end_logits=tensor([[2.1757, 0.0924, 2.2580]], grad_fn=<CloneBackward0>), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)
```

I could not find instructions for decoding these logits.

How can I decode the network output so that I get a string? Or is this method wrong and another way is needed here?

Comment: For those who have the same problem: I found its solution here:

https://www.kaggle.com/code/arunmohan003/question-answering-using-bert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as inspecting the model, the model is used for extractive question answering task. This means that it finds the relevant answer from the context (i.e., the given input) in the form of start and end token boundaries. With this in mind, you'll need the following steps to extract the relevant answer:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("KseniyaZ/sbert_large_nlu_ru")
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("KseniyaZ/sbert_large_nlu_ru")

s = 'Hi. How are you?'  # simple string with question
tok = tokenizer(s, return_tensors='pt')
res = model(**tok)

# Find the tokens with the highest start and end scores
answer_start = torch.argmax(res.start_logits)
answer_end = torch.argmax(res.end_logits) + 1  # add 1 to include the end token

# Convert these tokens to string
answer_tokens = tok.input_ids[0, answer_start:answer_end]
answer = tokenizer.decode(answer_tokens)
```

In fact, with the above information given, the following structure might make more sense in the context of the model you're using.

```
# Example context and question
context = "Paris is the capital and most populous city of France."
question = "What is the capital of France?"

# Encode context and question
input_text = tokenizer.encode_plus(question, context, return_tensors='pt')

# Get model output
output = model(**input_text)

# Find the tokens with the highest start and end scores
answer_start = torch.argmax(output.start_logits)
answer_end = torch.argmax(output.end_logits) + 1

# Convert these tokens to string
answer_tokens = input_text.input_ids[0, answer_start:answer_end]
answer = tokenizer.decode(answer_tokens)

print(answer) # paris
```